# React instagram api request with access token

Tags: reactjs, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to display IG feeds on my webpage.
I have generated the IG token from FB developers page.
What is the request URL for getting the IG feeds?
I'm using React JS project.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean your IG Profile Post? I never heard about getting someone IG Feed by Facebook API.

But if you mean getting yourself ig post you can access it via Facebook Graph API

Please check this out, maybe it is useful for you

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/media#get-media

Comment: Hi, yes I mean the IG Posts and Stories. And when I try to get data from Facebook graph api only images are received and not the video posts.
Also how do I receive the stories

Comment: Did you try this?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/stories/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media

Does you access it via media_url?

Comment: yes i have tried the same. Can you please tell me how to find the instagram user id for using it to get the IG stories

Comment: Did you try replace user id as 'me'?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/me

Comment: Hi I now can see the videos, Please can you help me get the Instagram user id for fetching the stories ?